# How to put static files such as videos behind auth in next.js webapp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, next.js

I want to serve some static content such as videos only to the visitors who are authorized. Routes can be secured and exposed only when user is authenticated. However, when showing video in that page, we need to keep it in public folder, which can be accessed without requirement of any authentication. For example

```
/pages/premium-content/content1.js //---showing video in this page which is placed at public/some/folder/video.mp4
```

The access to `./premium-content/content1` page may be allowed only for authenticated users, but how to prevent access to `public/some/folder/video.mp4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these assets in `assets` directory (you can name anything you like). And expose it via get API. Implement auth logic inside the API.